# If statement failing (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If statement logic in the inner line seems to work erroneously everytime (even when correct existing username and password are entered). I cannot find out why.

Code:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "customerdirectory");

    if($conn->connect_error) {
        echo("Connection Failed " . $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    if(isset($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"])) {    
        $username = stripslashes($_POST["user"]); 
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);

        $password = stripslashes($_POST["pass"]); 
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password); 

        $result = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name=='$username' AND password=='$password'";

        **if($conn->query($result)  === TRUE)**
            echo("Successful login: ".$username);
        else
            echo("The  username or password are incorrect!");

        $conn->close();
    };
 ?>
```

Comment: Do not use `stripslashes` on user data, especially passwords. It destroys content.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: `==` should be `=`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries
>   `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other
>   successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`.

Since you're executing a `SELECT` query, you should be expecting a `mysqli_result` object instead of `TRUE`. Should work if you change as follows:

```
if($conn->query($result))
    echo("Successful login: ".$username);
else
    echo("The  username or password are incorrect!");
```

Comment: May also be replaced by a simpler solution, working with whatever kind of query: `if ($conn->query($result))`.

Comment: What's with `=== TRUE` and the even more preposterous `!== FALSE`? `if` tests against logical conditions, and while empty strings and zero are technically false, these query functions return things that are intended to be evaluated logically.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. There is no `==` in mysql

Use this query

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name='$username' 
AND password='$password'";
```

Comment: @sergio Is the problem solved? If yes, feel free to upvote and mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (and other SQL languages) do not use the double equal sign syntax found in programming languages.  So your query should be `column = value` not `column == value`.

Answer (score 0):

insisted of writing `name=='$username' AND password=='$password';` try this below query

```
select * from customer where  name='$username' AND password='$password'";
```